# Error while trying to install ionic on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic4

How to **install** ionic 4 in **ubuntu** 18.04.Which version of **npm** nodejs **cordova android sdk** should go hand in hand for installing ionic 4 on ubuntu 18.04.Please do help me.I tried installing but i am getting error when i run the project.

```
 npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i"
    npm ERR! node v8.10.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
    npm ERR! code Unknown system error -122
    npm ERR! errno -122
    npm ERR! syscall close
```

Comment: did you install npm with nvm?

Comment: no i didnt use nvm

Comment: install nvm first it makes things easier...

Comment: after installing nvm, use nvm to install both node and npm packages then reinstall ionic and cordova on it.

Comment: @Yushin can you please tell me which all versions of ionic cordova android sdk nodejs and npm should i install such that it works without trouble

Comment: I am using NVM 0.34.0, NPM 6.9.0, NODE v11.9.0, IONIC CLI CLI 4.12.0, CORDOVA 9.0.0.

Comment: @Yushin so dont we need android sdk installed in our system to emulate it

Comment: yeah, you will need to install android studio and install the necessary tools.

Comment: @Yushin without android studio can't i install android-sdk.Which version of android sdk should i go for

Comment: android studio is your compiler so you cant do without it.

Comment: @Yushin thanks for your patience to help me.After installing android studio what all do we need to install in that

Comment: once you install android studio it will guide you on what you need to install, and once you try to compile in ionic it will guide you on how to set everything up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script: [Ionic Cordova installer for Ubuntu](https://github.com/nraboy/ubuntu-ionic-installer)

Its will Automatically install all required things. Your just have to update after this script.

Comment: it is for ubuntu 14.04 . Najam..I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: it will work. I have used this script for my Ubuntu 16.04 and it works like a charm. I think it will also work for 18.4